# What are the command line options to gitpods openvscode-server?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I looked over the readme of [openvscode-server](https://github.com/gitpod-io/openvscode-server) and I don't see all of the command line options listed there. I see the ones for docker but not the ones for running the standalone server. Initially I was trying to find the options to change the port and found it in the issues section of the repo. However, this prompted me to ask what other options are there seeing that some are listed while others seem to be hidden in the issues.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a set of command line options listed at https://github.com/gitpod-io/openvscode-server/blob/main/resources/server/bin-dev/code-web.js#L40-L67 including:

```
--port
--folder
--workspace
--driver
--enable-remote-auto-shutdown
--remote-auto-shutdown-without-delay
--logsPath
--github-auth
--enable-sync
--connection-token
--host
```

Update: there is a longer list here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/27a61bd9852cb8b808af99f0acedd3b5d3b9afd5/src/vs/server/serverEnvironmentService.ts#L12-L59

Answer (score 0):

**There are multiple of options:**

**Reference:** https://github.com/gitpod-io/openvscode-server/blob/main/src/vs/server/node/serverEnvironmentService.ts#L17:L85

```js
    /* ----- server setup ----- */

    'host': { type: 'string', cat: 'o', args: 'ip-address', description: nls.localize('host', "The host name or IP address the server should listen to. If not set, defaults to 'localhost'.") },
    'port': { type: 'string', cat: 'o', args: 'port | port range', description: nls.localize('port', "The port the server should listen to. If 0 is passed a random free port is picked. If a range in the format num-num is passed, a free port from the range (end inclusive) is selected.") },
    'socket-path': { type: 'string', cat: 'o', args: 'path', description: nls.localize('socket-path', "The path to a socket file for the server to listen to.") },
    'connection-token': { type: 'string', cat: 'o', args: 'token', deprecates: ['connectionToken'], description: nls.localize('connection-token', "A secret that must be included with all requests.") },
    'connection-token-file': { type: 'string', cat: 'o', args: 'path', deprecates: ['connection-secret', 'connectionTokenFile'], description: nls.localize('connection-token-file', "Path to a file that contains the connection token.") },
    'without-connection-token': { type: 'boolean', cat: 'o', description: nls.localize('without-connection-token', "Run without a connection token. Only use this if the connection is secured by other means.") },
    'disable-websocket-compression': { type: 'boolean' },
    'print-startup-performance': { type: 'boolean' },
    'print-ip-address': { type: 'boolean' },
    'accept-server-license-terms': { type: 'boolean', cat: 'o', description: nls.localize('acceptLicenseTerms', "If set, the user accepts the server license terms and the server will be started without a user prompt.") },
    'server-data-dir': { type: 'string', cat: 'o', description: nls.localize('serverDataDir', "Specifies the directory that server data is kept in.") },
    'telemetry-level': { type: 'string', cat: 'o', args: 'level', description: nls.localize('telemetry-level', "Sets the initial telemetry level. Valid levels are: 'off', 'crash', 'error' and 'all'. If not specified, the server will send telemetry until a client connects, it will then use the clients telemetry setting. Setting this to 'off' is equivalent to --disable-telemetry") },

    /* ----- vs code options ---    -- */

    'user-data-dir': OPTIONS['user-data-dir'],
    'enable-smoke-test-driver': OPTIONS['enable-smoke-test-driver'],
    'disable-telemetry': OPTIONS['disable-telemetry'],
    'disable-workspace-trust': OPTIONS['disable-workspace-trust'],
    'file-watcher-polling': { type: 'string', deprecates: ['fileWatcherPolling'] },
    'log': OPTIONS['log'],
    'logsPath': OPTIONS['logsPath'],
    'force-disable-user-env': OPTIONS['force-disable-user-env'],

    /* ----- vs code web options ----- */

    'folder': { type: 'string', deprecationMessage: 'No longer supported. Folder needs to be provided in the browser URL or with `default-folder`.' },
    'workspace': { type: 'string', deprecationMessage: 'No longer supported. Workspace needs to be provided in the browser URL or with `default-workspace`.' },

    'default-folder': { type: 'string', description: nls.localize('default-folder', 'The workspace folder to open when no input is specified in the browser URL. A relative or absolute path resolved against the current working directory.') },
    'default-workspace': { type: 'string', description: nls.localize('default-workspace', 'The workspace to open when no input is specified in the browser URL. A relative or absolute path resolved against the current working directory.') },

    'enable-sync': { type: 'boolean' },
    'github-auth': { type: 'string' },

    /* ----- extension management ----- */

    'extensions-dir': OPTIONS['extensions-dir'],
    'extensions-download-dir': OPTIONS['extensions-download-dir'],
    'builtin-extensions-dir': OPTIONS['builtin-extensions-dir'],
    'install-extension': OPTIONS['install-extension'],
    'install-builtin-extension': OPTIONS['install-builtin-extension'],
    'uninstall-extension': OPTIONS['uninstall-extension'],
    'list-extensions': OPTIONS['list-extensions'],
    'locate-extension': OPTIONS['locate-extension'],

    'show-versions': OPTIONS['show-versions'],
    'category': OPTIONS['category'],
    'force': OPTIONS['force'],
    'do-not-sync': OPTIONS['do-not-sync'],
    'pre-release': OPTIONS['pre-release'],
    'start-server': { type: 'boolean', cat: 'e', description: nls.localize('start-server', "Start the server when installing or uninstalling extensions. To be used in combination with 'install-extension', 'install-builtin-extension' and 'uninstall-extension'.") },


    /* ----- remote development options ----- */

    'enable-remote-auto-shutdown': { type: 'boolean' },
    'remote-auto-shutdown-without-delay': { type: 'boolean' },

    'use-host-proxy': { type: 'boolean' },
    'without-browser-env-var': { type: 'boolean' },

    /* ----- server cli ----- */

    'help': OPTIONS['help'],
    'version': OPTIONS['version'],
    'locate-shell-integration-path': OPTIONS['locate-shell-integration-path'],

    'compatibility': { type: 'string' },
```